# Unique IDs in Windows

Tags: windows, winapi

I want to know what unique IDs exists in Windows. I can think of the Volume Serial Number:

```
VOL C:
```

But this is a 32-bit number and so it is not too hard to have collisions.

There is also the HDD serial number:

```
wmic DISKDRIVE GET SerialNumber
```

Are there any other unique IDs?

**Note:** I know that I can generate my own GUID but this is not what I want.

Comment: Neither the volume serial number or the HDD serial number is guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: The industry standard is the MAC address of the onboard ethernet port.  (It is *almost* safe to assume that every machine will have one.)

Comment: MAC address is also often trivially changeable (especially in a VM).

Comment: @AndrewMedico: which is a feature, not a bug. :-)  The system administrator *should* be able to control the ID of the system if necessary.